# Adding files to perforce client

Tags: perforce

I have a handful of new files I want to add to my client. I moved my files to the proper location but every time I do "p4 add" I get the error "file(s) not in client view". I am confused why I am getting this error message since I am trying to add new files for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perforce correlates the location of the files on your workstation with the location of the files in the server's repository using your "workspace view", which is a crucial concept that you need to become familiar with.

Here's where to learn about it: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/intro/01_intro.html#1079899

Since you're working with the command line p4 tool, you'll use 'p4 client' to update your workspace definition and its view mapping.

You can also use the 'p4 where' command to understand how the mapping is translating filenames to and from the client and server formats.